# How to pass session value to next page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, ado.net

I am using .net and I am changing my .aspx.cs file to add the user choice in radio button to a row in database.

```
 private DataSet CreateData()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OptionID", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Option", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));

        DataRow row1 = table.NewRow();
        row1["OptionID"] = "1";
        row1["Option"] = "option 1";

        DataRow row2 = table.NewRow();
        row2["OptionID"] = "2";
        row2["Option"] = "two";

        DataRow row3 = table.NewRow();
        row3["OptionID"] = "3";
        row3["Option"] = "three";

        table.Rows.Add(row1);
        table.Rows.Add(row2);
        table.Rows.Add(row3);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(table);

        return ds;

    }

    private void bindRadioList()
    {
        DataSet ds = CreateData();
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = ds;
        RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Option";
        RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "OptionID";
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();

        if (RadioButtonList1.Items.Count > 0)
            RadioButtonList1.Items[0].Selected = true; //you can set a selected items you want.


    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["choice"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

    }
```

But I do not know how could I get this value at my last step when people click submit at the next page.
I tried:

```
  string sqlIns = "INSERT INTO Choice (Email, Choice) VALUES (@Email, @Choice)";
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
                conn.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, conn);
                cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Email", userRecord.email);
                cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Choice", (string)Session["choice"]);
                cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I got this error:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The
>   parameterized query '(@Email nvarchar(19),@Choice
>   nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO Choice (' expects the parameter '@Choice',
>   which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem and solution for this:
The problem is  Session["choice"] = Null and it is not acceptable under MSN standard. So I need to add this to prevent Null value :

```
   if ((string)Session["choice"] == null)
                {
                    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Choice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                   // cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Choice", (string)Session["choice"]);
                    cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Choice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (string)Session["choice"];
                }
```

To fix the null value, in .aspx file(I still can't figure out why the old code give null, but this one can avoid it)

```
   <div>                                                                                                                               
              <asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="Group1" Text="Choice 1" OnCheckedChanged="Button1_Click" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
              <asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioButton2" GroupName="Group1" Text="Choice 2" OnCheckedChanged="Button1_Click" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" /> 
              <asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioButton3" GroupName="Group1" Text="Choice 3" OnCheckedChanged="Button1_Click" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

and .cs file:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           // Session["choice"] = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            if (RadioButton1.Checked)
            {
                Session["choice"] = "Choice 1";
            }

            if (RadioButton2.Checked)
            {
                Session["choice"] = "Choice 2";
            }
            if (RadioButton3.Checked)
            {
                Session["choice"] = "Choice 3";
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Add` like;

```
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", userRecord.email);
cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Choice", (string)Session["choice"]);
```

From it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> `SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, Object)` overload has been
>   deprecated.  Use `AddWithValue(String parameterName, Object value)`
>   instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202"

Or you can use `(String, SqlDbType)` overload (which I *almost always* prefer instead of `AddWithValue`) of [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like (I assume both your column is `NVarChar` type);

```
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userRecord.email;
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@Choice", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = (string)Session["choice"];
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` adn `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"]))
using(SqlCommand cmdIns = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmdIns.CommandText = sqlIns;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: I still got this error with either ways you mentioned: The parameterized query '(@Email nvarchar(21),@Choice nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO Choice (' expects the parameter '@Choice', which was not supplied. Line 203:                    cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @user1314404 What is the value of `(string)Session["choice"]` exactly? What is your `cmdIns` looks like when you add your parameter values? Debug and tell me.

Comment: I cannot debug on my web server, it saids "unable to start debugging on the web server. ..could not find the requested resource". Sorry, can we do anything without debug, can we just build and see if there is error ? One note is on my several steps to the finish step, I have another place where they also use object "sender", will it cause conflict ?: protected void btnFinish_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {

Answer (score 0):

please check your store procedure where you are passing paramerters there you are not passing parameters @Choice

Comment: I thought session will store and pass the parameters ?